# SAS Macro to create multiple data sets based on the output of other macro

Tags: sas

There's a sas macro that creates multiple datasets based on the names..say, E_&name.
And, every data set has a "half_hr" column in it. Now, the problem is to segregate all the data sets E_&name. based on half_hr.. say E_&name.&half_hr.

Comment: How does your current macro work?  Post an example working off of either posted data or a sashelp dataset (click on the [tag:sas] tag for more info).  SASHELP.CITIDAY might work as an example dataset.

Comment: Note that splitting a dataset like this is usually not an efficient method. What's your downstream plans for these datasets?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that e_name is one of your e_&name datasets:

```
data e_name;
   input other_variables $ half_hr $;
   datalines;
    a 1
    b 17
    c 4
    d 12
    e 7
    ;
run;
```

You want to get a list of all values of half_hr in that dataset, and subset accordingly:

```
%macro subsetter;

    proc sql noprint;
        select distinct half_hr into: half_hr_list separated by " " from e_name;
    quit;

    data 
        %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&half_hr_list.));
        %let this_hh = %scan(&half_hr_list., &i.);
            e_name&this_hh.
        %end;;
        set e_name;
        %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&half_hr_list.));
        %let this_hh = %scan(&half_hr_list., &i.);
            if half_hr = "&this_hh." then output e_name&this_hh.;
        %end;;
    run;    

%mend subsetter;

%subsetter;
```